# Overlaying bar chart over a choropleth

Tags: data-visualization

My requirement is to create a Choropleth of World Map and 
1) overlay horizontal bar charts on specific regions
2) show horizontal barcharts over some other regions on tool tip.

Is this possible using the Google Visualization API? I considered drawing the choropleth using geochart or geomap but I do not know how to overlay bar charts over specific regions.

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks,
Parvathy.

Answer (score 0):

[VectorWorkz GeoChart](http://vectorworkz.com/) has the ability to do what you want. Take a look a this the [Online Demo here](http://vectorworkz.com/demo/). Browse to TwoGradientColors sample on the left which shows Choropleth rendering and Sales Details sample which shows rendering Bar charts on top of regions. These can be extended to create your exact requirement, if you are still interested contact the Support mail box.